# How can I display student fee in another div upon the courses selected using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a student registration system. I want new applicant to see the fee they have to pay upon the type of courses selected in the html select input field. I wrote a similar code but its not working for me. Please help.

JQuery code:

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(e) {

    if($("#coursestype").val()=="Database Technology"){

        $("#fee").html(" GHS 1,1200");
        }


});


  </script>
```

HTML CODE:

```
<label>IPMC Courses :</label>
  <select id="coursestype" name="coursestype">
    <option value="Software Engineering">Software Engineering</option>
    <option value="Database Technology">Database Tech</option>
    <option value="Graphic Web Design" selected="selected">Graphic Web Design</option>
    <option value="Computing">Computing</option>
    <option value="Business I.T">Business I.T</option>
    <option value="Business">Business</option>
    <option value="Tally Certified">Tally Certified</option>
    <option value="AuthoCAD 2010">AuthoCAD 2010</option>
    <option value="Foundation">Foundation</option>
    <option value="Certified Ethical Hacking">Certified Ethical Hacking</option>
  </select>

  Fee:<div id="fee"></div>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the `select` to `change`. This code will work:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#coursestype").change(function(){
        if($("#coursestype").val()=="Database Technology"){
            $("#fee").html(" GHS 1,1200");
        } else {
            $("#fee").html("All the money");
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57xa91jt/)